# Git merge to a old point in history

Tags: git, merge, rebase

I have a small repository, which I try to keep the more linear as possible (only one main branch). At some point in time I introduced breaking change in my code, put a tag at that point and continue.

Now, after a lot of commits and push and pull, I needed to extract some stuff from the old code. I checked out a new branch from an old commit, added a new folder with some auxiliary script (didn't change existing code) and commited to this branch.

I would like to merge again this branch in the main branch, instead of having a dangling dead branch. The problem is that I would like to merge it before the tag of the breaking change (these new script would break with the code in HEAD). Is it possible?

I read also about rebasing, but I am concerned because I've alredy pushed and pulled the newer commits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do (using [the merge strategy](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#_merge_strategies) `ours`):

```
git checkout master
git merge -s ours dead_branch
```

The dead_branch will be considered as merged in master, but none of dead_branch file will appear in (or modify any file of) `master`.
No need to merge "before" the tag. You merge the branch (and its scripts), except the changes introduced by that branch won't be reflected in `master`.

```
ours
```

> This resolves any number of heads, but **the resulting tree of the merge is always that of the current branch head, effectively ignoring all changes from all other branches**.
>   It is meant to be used to supersede old development history of side branches.
>
> Note that this is different from the `-Xours` option to the recursive merge strategy.